# Show an alert and set drop down to default

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown with blank value as default. When the user selects a particular value I want to show a alert and reset the dropdown to blank value. In the sample code below I've tried to put a condition for value 3. If the selected value is 3, show the alert and reset the dropdown to default.

the alert shows fine.. However the below does not work

```
document.getElementById("ddl").selectedIndex = "0";
```

I'm able to get until the alert, how can I trigger the action after the alert. Should I use a function instead?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function jsFunction(value)
    {
      if (value == 3) 
      {
      alert ("selected value does not match.. Please select the correct one");

       document.getElementById("ddl").selectedIndex = "0";

      }  
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <select id ="ddl" name="ddl" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value='1'>One</option>
      <option value='2'>Two</option>
      <option value='3'>Three</option>
    </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What action are you trying to trigger? Just change `.selectedIndex = "1"` to `.selectedIndex = "0"` and your dropdown changes back to default again.

Comment: The index is 0 based. To select the first one you set it to 0

Comment: These comment are correct, you must understand the the index is based on the where the selected value is positioned, NOT its value.

Comment: Yep, comments are correct: https://jsfiddle.net/edencorbin/53rmc03f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function jsFunction(_this)
        {
            var value = _this.value;
            if (value == 3) 
            {
                alert ("selected value does not match.. Please select the correct one");
                _this.value = "";
                document.getElementById("ddl").selectedIndex = "1";

            }  
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id ="ddl" name="ddl" onchange="jsFunction(this);">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
        <option value='3'>Three</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.getElementById("ddl").selectedIndex = "1";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("ddl").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ppeej4np/3/)

```js
document.getElementById("ddl").addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value == 3) {
    alert("selected value does not match.. Please select the correct one");
    this.children[0].setAttribute('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="ddl" name="ddl">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
  <option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
```